# Questions about Shunting-yard algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, parsing, expression

I've implemented an expression parser in C++ following [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), but have problems about the explanation on wikipedia. It's in 'The algorithm in detail' part:

> ```
> If the token is an operator, o1, then:
>
>     while there is an operator token o2, at the top of the operator stack and either
>
>         o1 is left-associative and its precedence is less than or equal to that of o2, or
>         o1 is right associative, and has precedence less than that of o2,
>
>             pop o2 off the operator stack, onto the output queue;
>
>     at the end of iteration push o1 onto the operator stack.
> ```

It says "`while there is an operator token o2`", by my undetstanding is "`while there is an operator or function token o2`".

Functions should be treated as operators and have a higher precedence than all traditional operators, is that right?

Comment: It's all depend on the language you're trying to implement. Also, is the actual function name really a "call operator" or is it the opening parenthesis? And what *is* a "function token"? How do you differ between a "function token" and any other symbolic name tokens (variables etc.)? And finally, isn't a "function call operator" (no matter what form it has) an *operator*?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Let's say that I was implementing 'C' language. I was just trying to implement the shunting yard algorithm following the details on wikipedia. And the explanation on wikipedia has a 'function' other than 'operator'. My understanding is that 'operator' here probably means the traditional operators  like in C or C++ languages and 'function' means the form like 'func(arg1,arg2...)'

Comment: @JoachimPileborg My code doesn't work properly except doing the changes detailed in my question. So I don't think wikipedia's explanation is clear enough, at least it confused me a lot.

Comment: You can't implement the C language with the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm. It is strictly an extension parser.

Comment: @EJP OK, I mean the math expression but with C-style

Comment: If you treat `function` as `operator`, you will get in trouble for some malformed expressions. I gave an example in an answer bellow. Think about that.

Comment: Sorry, iPad typo, it is strictly an *expression* parser. If you're trying to parse an extended expression grammar you need to *define* it, *before* you start writing a parser, or critiquing other parsers that have been working for 56 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that there should be no confusion between `operator` tokens and `function` tokens. In a well formed `expression`, arguments of each function must be enclosed between a left and a right parenthesis. While the parenthesis anywhere else is used to impose precedence or simply for clarity.
Based on this observation, the answer to your question

> Functions should be treated as operators and have a higher precedence than all traditional operators, is that right?

is No.

When it is said `operator` in the description of the algorithm, it means `operator` and when it is said `function` it means `function`. For a well formed `expression`, only the reading of a right parenthesis will lead you to pop the `function` which the right parenthesis closes the arguments list. Any confusion between `function` and `operator` will mislead your implementation to give an interpretation to wrong expressions. Imagine the following expression

```
4 + (sin 3 + 1)
```

If you treat a `function` like an operator, you will give a sense to that while the parenthesis might have simply be misplaced. You will also give a sense to this

```
4 - sin() 5*6
```

It gets more subtle when you consider functions with multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> It says "while there is an operator token o2", by my undetstanding is "while there is an operator or function token o2".
>
> Functions should be treated as operators and have a higher precedence than all traditional operators, is that right?

The text is correct.  If you have a function symbol on the operator stack, it means you are currently parsing function arguments and they all have go to the output queue before you move the function symbol there.

If you have an operator at the front of the input and a function symbol in the top of the operator stack, it means you're missing an opening parenthesis.

In some case you could get away with it like `sin a + b` according to the above algorithm will output `a b + sin`, which is the same as the output of `sin(a+b)`: in both cases (having `sin` on top of the stack, or having `(` on top of the stack), you don't enter that while loop above, but push `+` on the stack.

Comment: Yes you're right. I made mistake on 'pop function to output queue' when dealing with right parenthesis. Thanks to you all and well, it's not a good question here...What a stupid mistake I've made, sorry